# android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS,android.permission.READ_CONTACTS. Apps using these permissions in an APK are required to have a privacy policy set

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, google-play

android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS,android.permission.READ_CONTACTS. Apps using these permissions in an APK are required to have a privacy policy set. how to solve this error in play store?

Comment: What has this to do with javascript, css or html?

Comment: i have designed in html .css ,javascript,i have a problem in play store

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have privacy policy page to upload APKs with these permissions.

You can generate one from [here](https://www.freeprivacypolicy.com/) or use any privacy policy generators.

Upload in your server and provide it on Store Presence->Store Listing from the Google Play Console